# TSP - Traveling around a center

Tags: algorithm, geometry

For an optimization course we are encouraged to think of an algorithm for solving the Travelling Salesman Problem. I have an idea for a solution, and I think it's pretty rad. The steps for the algorithm are listed below. The order of the steps correspond to the order of the images.

1. Find the center of the points (red dot)
2. Travel around the center
3. Remove the largest line

The main sub-problem here is step 2. How does one go about traveling around a center point? Is there a good algorithm to do this?

I have another question about the algorithm's performance. How bad is this algorithm? Can you show me an example where it would give a worst-case answer?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For 'travel round the centre', you could construct the radii between the centre and the points, and 'sweep' a ray clockwise round. But imagine this: imagine your points are in two concentric circles, offset so that no two points share a radius. 'Travelling round the centre' here is going to spend a LOT of time going in and out between the two circles...

Comment: Why do you remove an edge in the end ?

Comment: To solve 2, compute all angles from the center to a vertex and sort the vertices by increasing angles.

Comment: In a traditional TSP, the traveler returns to the starting point. So Step 3 would not normally be done.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for the comments. I was able to implement the algorithm to find out that it does a terrible job for a lot of graphs. Was a good learning experience.